# How to get the bitcode when I use the cmake to compile the cppfile?

Tags: cmake, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I have searched the tutorial that I can use the command line to try : `clang -emit-llvm -o file.bc`  but how to write it in the cmakelists. I have to get all of bitcode file from the source code files.

Comment: Not the answer, but still related: https://github.com/klee/klee/blob/master/cmake/find_bitcode_compiler.cmake

Comment: You could overwrite `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` with your own script that just calls `clang` two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options possible:

- You can add particular flag to all your sources:
  `set ( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-emit-llvm")`
- Or if you still want to have .bc file and .o file at same time, you perhaps should introduce custom compile command, which is in fact two commands: first compiles .bc file, and second either just compiles .o file or converts .bc file into .o file by means of `llc`.
- If you compile with -flto flag, then all .o files will be in fact .bc files (you can check it with llvm-bcanalyzer for example). But in this case you have to link it with `ld.lld`

Comment: I have noticed that the third method, actually, which I have used, but do you know why it could be. I can use that .o file converted to the LLVM-IR code by ~dis~ , to which couldn't be transformed by the normal .o file.

Comment: Hm.. Please clarify in more details. In case of `-flto` there will be no normal .o files, except ones exported from outer libs. All project .o files will be in bytecode format. As for external .o files, this is sort of another issue, for you have them as-is.